# How to show the text at lock screen in Android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I interact with the Lockscreen layout to display text into it, like this app:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569812/how-can-i-interact-with-the-lockscreen-layout-to-display-text-into-it-like-this)

I want to show some text to the Android lock screen same as like 'I Like It' android app has implemented. You can see the app on Google play from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilikeit.main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not documented, but this will work ;-)

```
String message = "This is a test";
Settings.System.putString(context.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED, message);
```

Comment: Where should I put this code?

Comment: this is not working on android lollipop!!!