# show text view on lock screen using window manager in Marshmallow+

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-8.0-oreo, lockscreen, keyguard

In my app i was able to show text on lock screen using these params settings

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

but in android 6.0 and above where 
`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`
is deprecated i used 
`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`

it shows overlays on every activity successfully but unable to show the View on lock screen, anyone can help me how to show a button or text view on lock screen using any way in android 6.0 and above thanks

Comment: why not use local notification to display text on lock screen ?

Comment: have you tried this----> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569812/how-can-i-interact-with-the-lockscreen-layout-to-display-text-into-it-like-this

Comment: yes @akshay_shahane i tried it but this method is for older versions not working in 6.0 and above

Comment: notification is not my requirement, i wanna add floating buttons like facebook messenge on lock screen , android 6.0 and above

Comment: have you added this Search for permission android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW and WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT.

Comment: Yes i am using android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW in manifest and WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT is deprecated in android 6.0 instead i have to use  WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY but its not working